# Java FileReader, only as read

Tags: java, filereader, readonly

Does using the FileReader method in java, makes the file read only or does it still have to be stated

```
FileReader file = new FileReader(args[0]);    
BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(file);
```

Is *file* read only or would I need to state after the above code that I only want *file* to be read only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name specifies `FileReader`, this object will be having only methods to read a file.

For writing purposes we have `FileWriter` here.

File object will be having only read only access to your file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Was just double checking

Comment: Its okay ! you should accept answers here, if you find any one helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Objects `file` and `buffread` do not have any writing methods in them. So basically yes, they are read-only.

Answer (score 1):

None of the `Reader` APIs would actually change the writeability of a file on the file system, if that's what you mean. You can read from a file whether it's writeable or not (assuming it's readable!) `FileWriter` methods would fail with an `IOException` if the file is not writable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your question.
If you're asking about whether the *physical* file is being locked then it's platform dependent. On windows you are allowed to open multiple file streams and the file won't be read only.
If you're asking about the *file* variable in your code snippet then it's a **FileReader** object which means it can only read from the physical file.
For writing to a file see the [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) class.